# Item Appearances in the Hotbar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a map and I have needed a clock system for my map for a while now, and I stumbled across one on YouTube that I think is really cool. It is a clock that is in the player's hotbar, and uses heads to display numbers. This is how it looks in his video:

[image]

His video can be found on YouTube, [here](https://youtu.be/mXcFradkJBc). In his hotbar slots 2 through 9, what you can see are custom Minecraft heads that fill up the entire inventory slot. When I tried replicating this in my world, this is what I got:

[image]

I am wondering if this is just a bug because he was running back in 1.8.8, while I am always working in the latest snapshot (currently 16w05b). If this is not a bug then how do you get the numbers (player heads) to take up the full inventory slot like the first picture? It would make a timer easier to read and more visually appealing to the player.

Comment: Seems to me that  mod could accomplish this. I've written by own basic ones to change the look and feel of certain items and blocks, but haven't delved very far into it.

Comment: @TimS. the only issue I see with a mod is that I would be hosting this on my Realms server which does not currently support mods.

Comment: I believe he may use a custom texture pack where the models for the heads and rotated and scaled

Comment: @KeithM I have tried looking through the resource pack files and I can't find one containing the custom (or regular) player heads. I've looked online using Nova Skin (texture pack creator online) and they still don't have any files for editing the appearances of skulls.

Comment: @Dylpyckle13 I'm talking about the actual block models, using a program like BDCraft cubik you ca edit the models, so he probably took the played head model and rotated and scaled it so the front of the player is face-on in inventory view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the heads show up as a 3d block in the hotbar while items don't. try making a recource pack where you change the texture of items that you dont use to those numbers, or anything you want. then use the items instead of blocks. items should display just fine as they are displayed in 2d.

Comment: As I just mentioned to Keith above, I have looked through multiple webpages to create a custom resource pack and none online seem to offer changes to skulls.

Comment: But I said that you must not use skulls. Use items like potions you don't use or glass panes or something. Those are displayed in 2d as default where mobheads are displayed in 3d. Making it impossibile to my knowlage to do wat you wanted to do

Comment: Ah correct, my mistake. I had read the comment on the question and responded here. I'll see if I can get to work on it.